# SharePoint CSOM Provisioning with XML

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, taxonomy

I have started into [looking into](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP) the PnP samples into creating taxonomy.
The samples are pretty basic and laborious, in that you have to write code for the taxonomy you are creating like so:

```
// Create a Content Type Information object
        ContentTypeCreationInformation newCt = new ContentTypeCreationInformation();
        // Set the name for the content type
        newCt.Name = "Contoso Document";
        //Inherit from oob document - 0x0101 and assign 
        newCt.Id = "0x0101009189AB5D3D2647B580F011DA2F356FB2";
        // Set content type to be avaialble from specific group
        newCt.Group = "Contoso Content Types";
        // Create the content type
        ContentType myContentType = contentTypes.Add(newCt);
        cc.ExecuteQuery();
```

I am looking for a solution where I can take the exported XML provisioning file for Site Columns and Content Types and feed it to a sample program which can basically replicate the logic of the provisioning engine. Sure I could write some logic to parse the XML files and do this via the CSOM, but I am specifically after an OOB solution which will be able to parse all the possible combinations of XML definitions for SharePoint schema.

I do not see why there shouldn't be a pathway to supporting the provisioning logic, simply because we are moving to CSOM-based provisioning.

Thanks in advance.

Here are some examples of XML definitions of SharePoint taxonomy:

**Content Types**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="BaseContentTypes">
  </Module>

  <!-- Staff-->
  <ContentType ID='0x0100F92B529AD18F4D498737307175B60E37' Name='Staff' Group='Sukul.Demo' Description='' Overwrite='TRUE' Inherits='FALSE'>
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID='{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}' Name='ContentType' Required='FALSE' Hidden='FALSE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}' Name='Title' Required='FALSE' Hidden='TRUE' ShowInNewForm='TRUE' ShowInEditForm='TRUE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{e1b2b669-2302-43ef-8e77-828f30fe5521}' Name='FirstName1' Required='TRUE' Hidden='FALSE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{3ac38149-6751-4f6c-b85e-09541a696fc7}' Name='LastName' Required='TRUE' Hidden='FALSE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{64a42df2-a554-48d1-a4bb-1e7781ca1769}' Name='EmailAddress' Required='FALSE' Hidden='FALSE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{2112affc-de2f-4d1f-847c-8daa72ef97a8}' Name='ContactPhone' Required='FALSE' Hidden='FALSE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{1615cd6e-7f8a-4494-a3a3-942e82dd53c8}' Name='IsStaffRoomLeader' Required='FALSE' Hidden='FALSE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{42b95a14-8366-4008-aa89-1dbb77a2b873}' Name='DateOfBirth' Required='FALSE' Hidden='FALSE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{ae05e3c0-5f0a-4e4d-80a7-1d02207da877}' Name='FullName1' Required='FALSE' Hidden='FALSE' />
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>

  <!-- Guardian -->
  <ContentType ID='0x0100E24CA8452451C1448327FBDBF49A2A1C' Name='Guardian' Group='Sukul.Demo' Description='' Overwrite='TRUE' Inherits='FALSE'>
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID='{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}' Name='ContentType' Required='FALSE' Hidden='FALSE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}' Name='Title' Required='FALSE' Hidden='TRUE' ShowInNewForm='TRUE' ShowInEditForm='TRUE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{e1b2b669-2302-43ef-8e77-828f30fe5521}' Name='FirstName1' Required='TRUE' Hidden='FALSE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{3ac38149-6751-4f6c-b85e-09541a696fc7}' Name='LastName' Required='TRUE' Hidden='FALSE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{2112affc-de2f-4d1f-847c-8daa72ef97a8}' Name='ContactPhone' Required='FALSE' Hidden='FALSE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{64a42df2-a554-48d1-a4bb-1e7781ca1769}' Name='EmailAddress' Required='FALSE' Hidden='FALSE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{ae05e3c0-5f0a-4e4d-80a7-1d02207da877}' Name='FullName1' Required='FALSE' Hidden='FALSE' />
      <FieldRef ID='{bfbf5341-21f0-4771-a1fd-548429abe30b}' Name='GuardianType' Required='TRUE' Hidden='FALSE' />
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>

</Elements>
```

**Fields**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="BaseColumns">5fb64256-6264-4b5d-997b-588c2bf42715
  </Module>
  <!--Room-->
  <Field Type="TaxonomyFieldType" Group="Sukul.Demo" DisplayName="Room" ShowField="Term1033" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" ID="{db8695a1-b73a-4caa-b3ba-5b287a90b3e8}" StaticName="SukulFieldsRoom"
         Name="Room" SourceID="{2B9FE58F-2C41-4403-950D-FFFCDA0ECB5E}"
         List="Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList" WebId="~sitecollection" Version="2">
    <Default></Default>
    <Customization>
      <ArrayOfProperty>
        <Property>
          <Name>SspId</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q1:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">5fb64256-6264-4b5d-997b-588c2bf42715</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>GroupId</Name>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>TermSetId</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q2:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">f6d8e1b6-78c7-4f85-9773-3ba601ad0196</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>AnchorId</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q3:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>UserCreated</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q4:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>Open</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q5:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>TextField</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q6:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{3c9d245c-f5fa-415d-ab9d-d41f47f267b2}</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>IsPathRendered</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q7="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q7:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>IsKeyword</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q8="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q8:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>TargetTemplate</Name>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>CreateValuesInEditForm</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q9="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q9:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>FilterAssemblyStrongName</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q10="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q10:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>FilterClassName</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q11="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q11:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>FilterMethodName</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q12="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q12:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">GetFilteringHtml</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>FilterJavascriptProperty</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q13="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q13:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">FilteringJavascript</Value>
        </Property>
      </ArrayOfProperty>
    </Customization>
  </Field>
  <Field Type="Note" DisplayName="SukulFieldsRoom_0" StaticName="SukulFieldsRoom0" Name="SukulFieldsRoom0" ID="{3C9D245C-F5FA-415D-AB9D-D41F47F267B2}" ShowInViewForms="FALSE" Required="FALSE"
         Hidden="TRUE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" SourceID="{2B9FE58F-2C41-4403-950D-FFFCDA0ECB5E}" Overwrite="TRUE" />
  <!--DateOfBirth-->
  <Field Type="DateTime" DisplayName="DateOfBirth" Description="Date of Birth" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Overwrite="TRUE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateOnly" Group="Sukul.Demo" FriendlyDisplayFormat="Disabled" ID="{42b95a14-8366-4008-aa89-1dbb77a2b873}" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" StaticName="DateOfBirth" Name="DateOfBirth"></Field>
  <!-- AttendanceDateIn -->
  <Field Type="DateTime" DisplayName="AttendanceDateIn" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateTime" Group="Sukul.Demo" Overwrite="TRUE" FriendlyDisplayFormat="Disabled" ID="{bca57f3a-4257-4765-905f-0db32ffb3c8c}" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" StaticName="AttendanceDateIn" Name="AttendanceDateIn" CalType="0" Version="1"></Field>
  <!--IsStaffRoomLeader-->
  <Field Type="Boolean" DisplayName="IsStaffRoomLeader" Description="Is Staff a Room Leader" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Group="Sukul.Demo" ID="{1615cd6e-7f8a-4494-a3a3-942e82dd53c8}" Overwrite="TRUE" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" StaticName="IsStaffRoomLeader" Name="IsStaffRoomLeader">
    <Default>0</Default>
  </Field>
  <!--GenderOfChild-->
  <Field Type="Choice" DisplayName="GenderOfChild" Description="Gender of child" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="RadioButtons" FillInChoice="FALSE" Group="Sukul.Demo" ID="{f7ac699d-93a9-42ed-a3c5-8e42e8b05c96}" Overwrite="TRUE" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" StaticName="GenderOfChild" Name="GenderOfChild">
    <Default>Male</Default>
    <CHOICES>
      <CHOICE>Male</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>Female</CHOICE>
    </CHOICES>
  </Field>
  <!--AttendanceDateOut-->
  <Field Type="DateTime" DisplayName="AttendanceDateOut" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateTime" Group="Sukul.Demo" FriendlyDisplayFormat="Disabled" ID="{c481e5cf-98fa-4595-8f79-9fe18398b6ae}" Overwrite="TRUE" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" StaticName="AttendanceDateOut" Name="AttendanceDateOut" CalType="0" Version="1"></Field>
  <!--LastName-->
  <Field Type="Text" DisplayName="LastName" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" MaxLength="255" Group="Sukul.Demo" ID="{3ac38149-6751-4f6c-b85e-09541a696fc7}" Overwrite="TRUE" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" StaticName="LastName" Name="LastName"></Field>
  <!--FirstName-->
  <Field Type="Text" DisplayName="FirstName" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" MaxLength="255" Group="Sukul.Demo" ID="{e1b2b669-2302-43ef-8e77-828f30fe5521}" Overwrite="TRUE" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" StaticName="FirstName1" Name="FirstName1"></Field>
  <!--EmailAddress-->
  <Field Type="Text" DisplayName="EmailAddress" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" MaxLength="255" Group="Sukul.Demo" ID="{64a42df2-a554-48d1-a4bb-1e7781ca1769}" Overwrite="TRUE" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" StaticName="EmailAddress" Name="EmailAddress"></Field>
  <!--ContactPhone-->
  <Field Type="Note" DisplayName="ContactPhone" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" NumLines="6" RichText="FALSE" Sortable="FALSE" Group="Sukul.Demo" ID="{2112affc-de2f-4d1f-847c-8daa72ef97a8}" Overwrite="TRUE" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" StaticName="ContactPhone" Name="ContactPhone"></Field>
  <!--GuardianType-->
  <Field Type="TaxonomyFieldType" DisplayName="GuardianType" List="Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList" WebId="~sitecollection" Overwrite="TRUE" ShowField="Term1033" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Group="Sukul.Demo" ID="{bfbf5341-21f0-4771-a1fd-548429abe30b}" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" StaticName="GuardianType" Name="GuardianType" Version="1">
    <Default></Default>
    <Customization>
      <ArrayOfProperty>
        <Property>
          <Name>SspId</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q1:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">5fb64256-6264-4b5d-997b-588c2bf42715</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>GroupId</Name>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>TermSetId</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q2:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">bfe6d355-4566-491a-8c57-fde0233e56a2</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>AnchorId</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q3:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>UserCreated</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q4:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>Open</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q5:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>TextField</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q6:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{d2c22c6b-503c-4fae-b42c-da61b7e42e81}</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>IsPathRendered</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q7="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q7:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>IsKeyword</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q8="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q8:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>TargetTemplate</Name>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>CreateValuesInEditForm</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q9="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q9:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>FilterAssemblyStrongName</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q10="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q10:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>FilterClassName</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q11="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q11:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>FilterMethodName</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q12="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q12:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">GetFilteringHtml</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>FilterJavascriptProperty</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q13="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q13:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">FilteringJavascript</Value>
        </Property>
      </ArrayOfProperty>
    </Customization>
  </Field>
  <Field Type="Note" DisplayName="GuardianType_0" StaticName="bfbf534121f04771a1fd548429abe30b" Name="bfbf534121f04771a1fd548429abe30b" ID="{d2c22c6b-503c-4fae-b42c-da61b7e42e81}" ShowInViewForms="FALSE" Required="FALSE" Overwrite="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" />
  <!--FullName-->
  <Field Type="Calculated" DisplayName="FullName" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Overwrite="TRUE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateOnly" LCID="1033" ResultType="Text" ReadOnly="TRUE" Group="Sukul.Demo" ID="{ae05e3c0-5f0a-4e4d-80a7-1d02207da877}" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" StaticName="FullName1" Name="FullName1" Required="FALSE" Version="2">
    <Formula>=FirstName1&amp;" "&amp;LastName</Formula>
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef Name="FirstName1" ID="{e1b2b669-2302-43ef-8e77-828f30fe5521}" />
      <FieldRef Name="LastName" ID="{3ac38149-6751-4f6c-b85e-09541a696fc7}" />
    </FieldRefs>
  </Field>
  <!--Date of Event-->
  <Field Type="DateTime" DisplayName="Date Of Event" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateTime" Overwrite="TRUE" Group="Sukul.Demo" FriendlyDisplayFormat="Disabled" ID="{dc0f6741-0705-48f2-9669-7c19a1f63eae}" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" StaticName="Date_x0020_Of_x0020_Event" Name="Date_x0020_Of_x0020_Event">
    <Default>[today]</Default>
  </Field>
  <!--Start Datetime-->
  <Field Type="DateTime" DisplayName="Start DateTime" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Overwrite="TRUE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateTime" Group="Sukul.Demo" FriendlyDisplayFormat="Disabled" ID="{afaa7c42-39de-44c8-8d09-6abd5e8f6750}" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" StaticName="Start_x0020_DateTime" Name="Start_x0020_DateTime" CalType="0" Version="1"></Field>
  <!--End Datetime-->
  <Field Type="DateTime" DisplayName="End DateTime" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Overwrite="TRUE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateTime" Group="Sukul.Demo" FriendlyDisplayFormat="Disabled" ID="{c2155dd9-d5dc-49ab-8ada-2cd336936ab7}" SourceID="{71873de0-8937-47ab-a03e-1a5a66dfd39a}" StaticName="End_x0020_DateTime" Name="End_x0020_DateTime" CalType="0" Version="1"></Field>

</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1):

For fields you can achieve this quite easily, using either CSOM or SSOM, by feeding the field XML to AddFieldAsXml, roughly as follows:

```
web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(oneFieldDefinition.OuterXml, false, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
```

I'm not aware of any similar capability for content types, though.

Comment: That's great feedback! I will try this out and update the thread later..